# Prove the absolute inequality in the integrals

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals

Let $a\in R$, $f: \Bbb [a,\infty)   \to\Bbb R$  be an integrable function on every [a, b] where a $<$ b. Suppose $$\int_a^{\infty}|f(x)|\\ $$ and $$\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\\ $$ converge.  Prove:
$$\left|\int_a^{\infty} f(x)\right| \le \ \int_a^{\infty}|f(x)|\\$$

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Do you know the definitions of the things you wrote down?

Comment: basically what I wrote down as 'suppose', I proved alone. I tried using the triangle inequality, but to no success. as well as the integral comparison test, but wasn't sure how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

$$
 -|f(x)| \le f(x) \le |f(x)| \quad \text{ for all } x \ge a
$$
implies
$$
-\int_a^{\infty}|f(x)| \, dx \le \int_a^{\infty}f(x) \, dx \le \int_a^{\infty}|f(x)| \, dx
$$
and therefore
$$
\left|\int_a^{\infty} f(x) \, dx \right| \le \ \int_a^{\infty}|f(x)| \, dx \, .
$$
The last step uses that for real numbers $a$ and $b$,  $|a| \le b$ is equivalent to $-b \le a \le b$.